# github upload apk: something went really wrong

Tags: android, github, release

Using Android Studio, I added a project - source code and apk - to github. I then attempted to release it, hoping to have the apk as a single downloadable asset.

However, when dragging my apk to the release form, I get an error: "Something went really wrong, and we can’t process that file. Try another file."

You can view the release at:
https://github.com/PeriHartman/perinote-call-log/releases/tag/v1.0

Comment: You probably shouldn't host large binaries on GitHub. Git doesn't do well with big files; it will increase the size of your repository and slow down over time. If you want to distribute your APKs, you might look into storing them on a cloud drive like Amazon S3 or using some kind of continuous delivery solution to auto-publish it to the Play Store.

Comment: Is 1.7 MB considered large?

Comment: Not really, but it's really not good practice to do it. Take the time and 
set up continuous delivery for your project if you plan to work on it long term, or just host it in a shared folder somewhere and provide a link to it in your readme. https://robinwinslow.uk/2013/06/11/dont-ever-commit-binary-files-to-git/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I search a little in web and in some sites people with same issue indicate that it's a browser issue. U are using Firefox?

If u are using Firefox try do it with Chrome and let me know if its works!